# Show icon in center of image on mouse hover

Tags: jquery, css

I've been trying for a few days to show a search icon in a center of my 159 by 149 image
on mouse hover. But I'm always getting some problem and now I don't understand what is happening. Can anyone that already tried to do this exercise give some help? Thanks!

HTML:

```
<article class="posts">
    <div style="float:left; position:relative;position: relative; clear: both; background-size:contain; background-image: url('imagens/image1.png'); width: 159px; height: 149px; padding-right: 10px; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
        <a href="#" class="search_icon_hover" style="display: none; margin-left: 0px; background-color:#666; opacity:0.9; transition: 0.3s; position:absolute; top:0; bottom: 0; left:0; right: 0;">
            <span id="icon_search"><I class ="fa fa-search-plus" > </I>Hover</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</article>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".posts").mouseenter(function(e){
        console.log('enter');
        $((e.toElement)).find('a.search_icon_hover').show();
    }).mouseleave(function(elemento) {
        $((e.toElement)).find('a.search_icon_hover').hide();
    });;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Hm...well, the problem primarily lies with your usage of `e.toElement`. If you try to run this code:

```
$(".posts").mouseenter(function(e){
    console.log(e.toElement);
});
```

You'll find that `e.toElement` is actually returning `undefined`. Rather than using this approach, let's use the `this` keyword instead. (Here's [some information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) about it, if you were curious to know more.) Your JavaScript would therefore be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".posts").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).find('a.search_icon_hover').show();
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).find('a.search_icon_hover').hide();
    });
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8QnA/5/) to demonstrate the script in action. I think it produces the behaviour you're seeking. Isn't `this` great? Hope this helped! Let me know if you have any questions.

**EDIT** In response to your additional comment (I must have overlooked this in my initial answer), I've added some more code so the hover text is centred. To do this, I added to `#icon_search` some new CSS, so the HTML looks like this:

```
<span id="icon_search" style="display:block; position:relative; top:50%; margin-top:-8px;">
    <I class ="fa fa-search-plus" > </I>Hover
</span>
```

Using this CSS, the hover text will remain in the center of the container, regardless of the container's size. Note that for multi-line content, you'll need to increase the negative `margin-top` accordingly.

Now, for the fading in/out, you can't actually use CSS transitions to animate the `display` property, so we need a different approach. I felt it would be easier (and a little more robust across browsers) to just move that fading fully to the jQuery. So I removed `transition:0.3s` from your inline styles, and changed the JavaScript code to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".posts").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).find('a.search_icon_hover').fadeIn(300);
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).find('a.search_icon_hover').fadeOut(300);
    });
});
```

Here's a [new JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L8QnA/9/) to show you what this achieves. Let me know if you were looking to do anything else.

Comment: thank you, very good answer, although I read this site carefully and your example in jsFiddle but my problem already continues. I created a jsFiddle to see what's happening to me, this image that I'm trying to make this hover effect compared to other image that have no effect, the texts stick in the image and imagme image is larger than the others that are not with the hover effect, and can not understand why! [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ritz/L8QnA/6/)

Comment: I've updated my answer in response to your comment. Let me know if there's anything else you need me to touch on.

Comment: Thanks for your attention but the problem still remais, bacause the hover icon dont appears in the center of image and the image that I´m trying to give the effect  have different size then the others that don´t have yet the hover effect..

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what you mean by that. The "Hover" text seems to appear in the center of the first box of the JSFiddle, unless that's not what you mean by "the center of the image". Could you take a screenshot and circle the area you actually want the "Hover" text to appear?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [**LIVE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6mh3r/7/)

#### HTML

```
<article class="posts">
    <div style="float:left; position:relative;position: relative; clear: both; background-size:contain; background-image: url('imagens/image1.png'); width: 159px; height: 149px; padding-right: 10px; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
          <a href="#" class="search_icon_hover" style="background-color:#666; opacity:0.9; transition: 0.3s; position:absolute; top:0; bottom: 0; left:0; right: 0;text-align:center;vertical-align: middle;padding-top:62px;">
             <span id="icon_search">Hover</span>
         </a>
    </div>
</article>
```

#### JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".posts").mouseenter(function(e){
        console.log('enter');
        $((e.toElement)).find('a.search_icon_hover').show();
    }).mouseleave(function(e) {
        $((e.toElement)).find('a.search_icon_hover').hide();
    });;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but the jsfiidle is not working how I want, maybe I explain my issue bad, sorry! I just want to show the search icon on mouse hover with a fade transition effect. But I´m not having the transition effect and my image with the hover effect is getting different from other images that still do not have the effect I want to hover. Like I have here: http://jsfiddle.net/ritz/L8QnA/6/

Comment: Ok so you want to Hover text set on center - check this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L8QnA/7/ 
I am really helpfuly then give me some vote credit to help me future. Thank you

Comment: Yes its that That what I was trying, thank you very much!I just having now the problem of transition, because my "transition: 0.3s;" is not working and the problem of my image with the over effect is bigger then the others and I´m not understanding why!

Comment: Thank you for posting, I found this typo problem that i solve.